# replace strings between two patterns

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I would like to replace (using sed/awk/tr) all the strings between `CleanAgrobacterium` and `_gene` by `ZZZ` in my  file  A.nwk:

```
(((CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_str__C58_DE0068_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-FS783_RS12830:0,CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_str__C58_DE0067_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-FS653_RS12825:0):0.056789,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_GV2260_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-EML4058_RS17445:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_1D1416_Chromosome_Proteins_gene-NQG32_RS17500:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_PDC82_Contig_Proteins_gene-BLT49_RS14090:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_N3394_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-G6L76_RS17395:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_12D13_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-At12D13_RS18010:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_Bi46_Contig_Proteins_gene-LQ162_RS02700:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_ARqua1_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-HI842_RS18310:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_N4094_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-G6L42_RS17400:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_GV3101__pMP90_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-EML485_RS17435:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_Kin001_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-FY134_RS17775:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_LBA645_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-KXJ62_RS17445:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_Di1525a_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-G6L89_RS17735:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_NFIX02_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-BLR22_RS16795:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_Arqua_Contig_Proteins_gene-EXN51_RS19140:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_str__J-07_J-07_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-AGR8A_RS20015:0,CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_1D132_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-At1D132_RS18580:0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_EHA105_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-EML540_RS17455:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_RIT-As-3_Contig_Proteins_gene-ORG40_RS11815:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_2788_Contig_Proteins_gene-G6L39_RS17590:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_BG5_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-F3P66_RS17495:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_Bi05_Contig_Proteins_gene-LQV40_RS07170:0,(CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_str__C58_C58_Complete_Genome_Proteins_gene-ATU_RS17440:0,CleanAgrobacterium_fabrum_NFIX01_Scaffold_Proteins_gene-BMY00_RS16800:0):0):0):0):0):0):0);
```

```bash
sed "/CleanAgrobacterium/,/gene-/d" A.nwk
```

Comment: This replace only either the pattern `CleanAgrobacterium` or  `_gene`

Comment: my bad, you're right; what's the expected output? _"**all the strings between**"_ is a little ambiguous.

Comment: Please come up with sample input where we don't need a scroll bar to view it so it's as easy as possible for us to help you. Also, provide a few different sample input lines that cover all your requirements, especially the cases where a script is likely to fail such as multiple `_gene` strings on a line, and/or `_gene` with no `CleanAgrobacterium` and vice-versa, etc. Also add the expected output as @Fravadona already requested. We can't test a potential solution given just input, especially just 1 line of input.

Comment: @Slimanekhayi Please accept ✓ one of the answers if helpful or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a range, you could make the pattern more specific for the example data matching 1 or more alphanumeric chars or `-` or `_` in between using `[[:alnum:]_-]\+`  and replace the match(es) with `zzz`

```
sed "s/CleanAgrobacterium[[:alnum:]_-]\+_gene/zzz/g" A.nwk
```

Output

```
(((zzz-FS783_RS12830:0,zzz-FS653_RS12825:0):0.056789,(zzz-EML4058_RS17445:0,(zzz-NQG32_RS17500:0,(zzz-BLT49_RS14090:0,(zzz-G6L76_RS17395:0,(zzz-At12D13_RS18010:0,(zzz-LQ162_RS02700:0,(zzz-HI842_RS18310:0,(zzz-G6L42_RS17400:0,(zzz-EML485_RS17435:0,(zzz-FY134_RS17775:0,(zzz-KXJ62_RS17445:0,(zzz-G6L89_RS17735:0,(zzz-BLR22_RS16795:0,(zzz-EXN51_RS19140:0,(zzz-AGR8A_RS20015:0,zzz-At1D132_RS18580:0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0):0,(zzz-EML540_RS17455:0,(zzz-ORG40_RS11815:0,(zzz-G6L39_RS17590:0,(zzz-F3P66_RS17495:0,(zzz-LQV40_RS07170:0,(zzz-ATU_RS17440:0,zzz-BMY00_RS16800:0):0):0):0):0):0):0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This replaces all the text *between* `CleanAgrobacterium` and `_gene` by `ZZZ`:

```
sed -E 's/(CleanAgrobacterium).*(_gene)/\1ZZZ\2/g' A.nwk
```

But the result is probably not what you would expect. I assume you want ungreedy matching of the text in-between (`.*`). For that, use perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(CleanAgrobacterium).*(_gene)/\1ZZZ\2/g' A.nwk
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/CleanAgrobacterium/&\n/g
        s/gene-/\n&/g
        s/(CleanAgrobacterium)\n[^\n]*\n(gene-)/\1ZZZ\2/g
        s/\n//g' file
```

Append a newline to `CleanAgrobacterium` and prepend a newline to `gene-`.

Replace everything that is not a newline between the desired words.

Remove any introduced newlines.

N.B. This does not cater for matches on separate lines. In this case use something like:

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x
        s/\n/@@@NEWLINE%%%/g
        s/CleanAgrobacterium/&\n/g
        s/gene-/\n&/g
        s/(CleanAgrobacterium)\n[^\n]*\n(gene-)/\1ZZZ\2/g
        s/\n//g
        s/@@@NEWLINE%%%/\n/g' file
```

This slurps the whole file into memory, replaces all newlines by a unique string, then applies the first solution and tidies up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed 's/gene-/gene-\n/g' < A.nwk | sed 's/CleanAgrobacterium.*gene-/CleanAgrobacteriumZZZgene-/g' | sed -n ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;p' > output.txt
```

works with GNU Sed 4.9  using Linux .

Answer (score 0):

Yet another sed solution. It replaces all **THIS** with **THAT** (with your samples in reality but more readable here) between START and END in "fooSTART**THIS**ENDfooSTART**THIS**ENDfoo"
and outputs "fooSTART**THAT**ENDfooSTART**THAT**ENDfoo".

```
$ sed -E 's/(CleanAgrobacterium)([^_]|_(_|g(_|e(_|n_)))*([^_g]|g([^_e]|e([^_n]|n[^_e]))))*(_(_|g(_|e(_|n_)))*(g(e?|en))?)?(_gene)/\1ZZZ\2/g' file
```

The solution is non-greedy and relies on regex capturing groups `(CleanAgrobacterium)`and `(_gene)`, their backreferences `\1`, `\2` and what is between them
`([^_]|_(_|g(_|e(_|n_)))*([^_g]|g([^_e]|e([^_n]|n[^_e]))))*(_(_|g(_|e(_|n_)))*(g(e?|en))?)?`
(*not `_gene`*) getting replaced by `ZZZ`. You could use it in, for example; GNU awk's `gensub()` which supports backreferencing:

```
$ gawk '{print gensub(/(CleanAgrobacterium)([^_]|_(_|g(_|e(_|n_)))*([^_g]|g([^_e]|e([^_n]|n[^_e]))))*(_(_|g(_|e(_|n_)))*(g(e?|en))?)?(_gene)/,"\\1ZZZ\\2","g",$0)}' file
```

Comment: Man, that looks messy.